# What does 浮く mean here?

Tags: meaning

A high-schooler was thinking about what to do during lunch

> 大人だったら別に一人メシなんて普通なんだけど...高校ジャやっぱ浮く...よなぁ

I am uncertain what 浮く means here. I think it means in high school, there are many ways to eat?

Comment: See [浮く](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8F).  It would seem that the speaker is saying they feel left out if they must eat alone (whereas for adults, eating alone seems nothing special).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage of 浮く is defined in several dictionaries as follows.

> ###### [浮く](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8F) <sub>(jisho.org)</sub>
>
> 4. to feel out of it; to be cut off (e.g. from those around you); to feel out of place​
>
>    > 若者ばかりのそのコンサート会場で、おじさんの私はすっかり周りから浮いていた。
>    > Being at the concert hall full of young kids made an old duffer like me feel out of tune.

> ###### [浮く](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8F-439257) <sub>(デジタル大辞泉)</sub>
>
> 4. ある集団の中で仲間との接触が薄くなる。遊離する。「仲間から—・いた存在」

> ###### 浮く <sub>(大修館書店 明鏡国語辞典 3rd ed)</sub>
>
> 7. 集団になじまない状態になる。「場違いな服装で周囲から浮く」